# my first linq conncetion, will not connect to repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

Hope someone can help me out of this issue.
Im trying to get data from a mdf database into a repeater.

I have created the dbml file, its called "Thedatabaseconnection.dbml", i have the web.config file and in that i have a connectionstring called "masterDBConnectionString".

I have this vb class file.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Web

Public Class connectionDBtesttable

Private _testId As Integer
Private _testCat As String
Private _testInfo As String
Private _testNumbers As Integer
Private _testDate As Date

Public Property test_id() As Integer
    Get
        Return _testId
    End Get

    Set(value As Integer)
        _testId = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property test_cat() As String
    Get
        Return _testCat
    End Get

    Set(value As String)
        _testCat = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property test_info() As String
    Get
        Return _testInfo
    End Get

    Set(value As String)
        _testInfo = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property test_numbers() As Integer
    Get
        Return _testNumbers
    End Get

    Set(value As Integer)
        _testNumbers = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property test_datetime() As Date
    Get
        Return _testDate
    End Get

    Set(value As Date)
        _testDate = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

I have this code_behind

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq

Partial Class _default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Call linqdb()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub linqdb()
    Using datacontext As New ThedatabaseconnectionDataContext()
        Dim query = From a In datacontext.GetTable(Of testtable)() _
                    Order By a.test_id Descending _
                    Select a

        Repeater1.DataSource = query.ToList
        Repeater1.DataBind()
    End Using
End Sub

End Class
```

I have this main page

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But i cant get the data from the DB into the repeater1...
Can someone plz help me, this is my first LinQ connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified what markup should be rendered for each item in the repeater. As an example try altering your markup as follows:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Info: <%# Eval("test_info") %>
        Date: <%# Eval("test_datetime") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This will simply render info and date for each item returned from the DB. You can specify more complicated markup if you want to. For more info on this topic you can check out the [MSDN page about the Repeater control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx).

Comment: or if you want to automatically generate column then use datagridvew control

Comment: Uhm what error to make, but I admit I am also not Prof. for this, just think it is fun to 'play' with, you know what ... Thanks very much for your help.